# What is the grammar of the sentence like "Deleting a node z from .." that usually accompanied with figures in textbook

Tags: verbs

When I am going to write some explanations in a step-by-step form that accompany with diagram, I found out it is difficult to decide what the subject is, for example:

> Calculate the sum.

Maybe it is OK if I put the "We" or "Let's" before it, and make grammar right, but thing becomes weird if I do it on every sentence in the situation like that.
I look back to my textbook, I could learn the sentence like:

> Deleting a node z from a binary search tree.

But I cannot understand the grammar of this sentence.

Comment: A sentence like "Calculate the sum" is usually an **imperative**.  It doesn't really have a subject, it just means something like "You must ______".  But I wonder if what's confusing you is that labels and topics are usually written in something like [headlinese](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-headlinese-1690921).

Comment: @stangdon thank you for your quick reply! it makes sense to me to see "Calculate the sum." as an imperative. But "Deleting a node z from a binary search tree" which describes what actions show in the figure still confuse me, why in V-ing form?And it is possible to have 3 to 4 sentences to compose the description accompanied with figure, is the situation still fit to `headlinese`?

Comment: (This figure shows) Deleting a node z from a binary search tree.

Comment: @Davo, really appreciate your explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no formal rules for captioning diagrams; the goal is usually clarity and brevity. I suggest you understand this caption as:

> *(This figure shows)* Deleting a node z from a binary search tree.